# Select a list item, and add the item to another list (with jquery, javascript??)

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

Left i have a list with all names. I select one name and click on a button 'add' (to the right list).
Also i want to 'remove' items form the right list, back to the left list.

Someone an example?